# jq split multiple text files into multiple arrays

Tags: json, yaml, jq

I have the issue I have some files that have as content multiple key value pairs that I'd like to transform into multiple arrays.

Let me illustrate what I mean with some produced examples. First the content of the files:

```
# cat content/1.yaml
time: "2020-09-14T22:33:40Z"
id: ed1d4321
name: One
description: 'Here is number "one"
  this is good'

# cat content/2yaml
time: "2021-09-14T22:33:40Z"
id: eg134841
name: Two
description: 'Here is number "two"
  best of all'
newkey: value
```

In the next step I merge these files together into one blob containing the filenames as well which I want to keep:

```
# for file in $(ls content/*yaml); do echo filename: $file; cat $file; done
filename: content/1.yaml
time: "2020-09-14T22:33:40Z"
id: ed1d4321
name: One
description: 'Here is number "one"
  this is good'
filename: content/2yaml
time: "2021-09-14T22:33:40Z"
id: eg134841
name: Two
description: 'Here is number "two"
  best of all'
newkey: value
```

And now the issue begins, how to bring this together into json arrays?

That's what I came up with up to now:

```
# for file in $(ls content/*yaml); do echo filename: $file; cat $file; done | jq -Rn '[inputs|split(": ")] | map({(.[0]): .[1]})'
[
  {
    "filename": "content/1.yaml"
  },
  {
    "time": "\"2020-09-14T22:33:40Z\""
  },
  {
    "id": "ed1d4321"
  },
  {
    "name": "One"
  },
  {
    "description": "'Here is number \"one\""
  },
  {
    "  this is good'": null
  },
  {
    "filename": "content/2yaml"
  },
  {
    "time": "\"2021-09-14T22:33:40Z\""
  },
  {
    "id": "eg134841"
  },
  {
    "name": "Two"
  },
  {
    "description": "'Here is number \"two\""
  },
  {
    "  best of all'": null
  },
  {
    "newkey": "value"
  }
]
```

That's is already close but some issues I still have to solve which I don't find a solution for:

1. The filenames are not spread into separate arrays.
2. the `time` field should not have the escaped quoted strings. I'd like to have a solution that iterates over all fields and would expand these contents out of of the quotes like here as example `"time": "2021-09-14T22:33:40Z"`
3. `description` value is spread over multiple lines and I'd like to see them merged into one value but that's not what happens as of now, so should look like that: `"description": "Here is number \"two\"  best of all`. The single quotes should not be kept.

So at the end the outcome should be rather like that:

```
[
  {
    "filename": "content/1.yaml",
    "time": "2020-09-14T22:33:40Z",
    "id": "ed1d4321",
    "name": "One",
    "description": "Here is number \"one\"  this is good"
  },
  {
    "filename": "content/2yaml",
    "time": "2021-09-14T22:33:40Z",
    "id": "eg134841",
    "name": "Two",
    "description": "Here is number \"two\"  best of all",
    "newkey": "value"
  }
]
```

Comment: Your desired result isn't valid JSON, though. Did you swap `[]` and `{}` there?

Comment: Oh gosh, you are right. Corrected that.

Answer (score 1):

The following handles one file at a time, and presupposes an invocation of jq using the -R and -s command-line options (`jq -Rs`).  Combining the results for more than one file is left as an exercise. (Hint: for the filename, use `input_filename`.)

```
  def objectify:
    capture("(?<key>[^:]+): *(?<value>.*)")
    | .value = (.value | (fromjson? // .))
    | [.]
    | from_entries;

  gsub("\n  *"; " ")        # join dangling text
  | . / "\n"                # split
  | map(select(length>0))   # ignore ""
  | map(objectify)          # {key, value}
  | add
```

Comment: Nice. I have tried out now this one and it's an interesting solution too. Thank you.

I move the jq inside the for loop and that already made the trick:
```
# for file in $(ls content/*yaml); do (echo filename: $file; cat $file) | jq -Rs 'def objectify:  capture("(?<key>[^:]+): *(?<value>.*)") | .value = (.value | (fromjson? // .)) | [.] | from_entries; gsub("\n  *"; " ") | . / "\n" | map(select(length>0)) | map(objectify) | add'; done | jq -s
```

Comment: Result is

{
  "filename": "content/1.yaml",
  "time": "2020-09-14T22:33:40Z",
  "id": "ed1d4321",
  "name": "One",
  "description": "'Here is number \"one\" this is good'"
}
{
  "filename": "content/2yaml",
  "time": "2021-09-14T22:33:40Z",
  "id": "eg134841",
  "name": "Two",
  "description": "'Here is number \"two\" best of all'",
  "newkey": "value"
}

Comment: @A.H. - Yes, the "smart" editor outsmarted this editor.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to citate inside comment. Let me try again:

`[
  {
    "filename": "content/1.yaml",
    "time": "2020-09-14T22:33:40Z",
    "id": "ed1d4321",
    "name": "One",
    "description": "'Here is number \"one\" this is good'"
  },
  {
    "filename": "content/2yaml",
    "time": "2021-09-14T22:33:40Z",
    "id": "eg134841",
    "name": "Two",
    "description": "'Here is number \"two\" best of all'",
    "newkey": "value"
  }
]
`

Answer (score 0):

This is something probably better suited for [`yq`](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) instead of trying to re-implement a YAML parser.

Something like this would work:

```bash
yq eval-all -o=json '[{"filename": filename} + .]' *.yaml
```

resulting in

```json
[
  {
    "filename": "1.yaml",
    "time": "2020-09-14T22:33:40Z",
    "id": "ed1d4321",
    "name": "One",
    "description": "Here is number \"one\" this is good"
  },
  {
    "filename": "2.yaml",
    "time": "2021-09-14T22:33:40Z",
    "id": "eg134841",
    "name": "Two",
    "description": "Here is number \"two\" best of all",
    "newkey": "value"
  }
]
```

Comment: I am aware of yq, however I wanted to omit additional tools. I'd like to stick with bash and jq only.

Comment: @AndréLetterer If you know a lot about the input, that might work, but as soon as you encounter an edge case, your solution will break. For example, currently, strings can't contain multiple colons. And think about the complexity of YAML string quoting alone.

Comment: `[{"filename": filename} + .]` would be even simpler

Comment: @pmf Indeed! It felt simple after failed `ireduce` attempts ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial solution -- the values are not yet "cleaned". This is left as an excercise to the reader :-)

Start with `jq --slurp --raw-input`:

```
# split lines
split("\n")
# join lines starting with whitespace with previous line
| reduce .[] as $l (
    null;
    if $l | startswith(" ") then .[-1] += $l else . += [$l] end
)
# split on first colon, returning an array of objects like {key: X, value: Y}
| map(capture("^(?<key>[^:]+):\\s*(?<value>.*)$"))
# combine these simple objects into bigger objects but begin a new objects when encountering "filename"
| reduce .[] as $e (null; 
    if $e.key == "filename" then . += [{}] else . end
    | .[-1][$e.key] = $e.value
)
```

The output is this:

```
[
  {
    "filename": "content/1.yaml",
    "time": "\"2020-09-14T22:33:40Z\"",
    "id": "ed1d4321",
    "name": "One",
    "description": "'Here is number \"one\"  this is good'"
  },
  {
    "filename": "content/2yaml",
    "time": "\"2021-09-14T22:33:40Z\"",
    "id": "eg134841",
    "name": "Two",
    "description": "'Here is number \"two\"  best of all'",
    "newkey": "value"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found another answer to that which is not using yq but using python which is most probably installed on lots of machines:

```
# for file in $(ls content/*yaml); do (echo filename: $file; cat $file) | python -c 'import yaml; import json; import sys; print(json.dumps(yaml.safe_load(sys.stdin)));' ; done | jq -s
[
  {
    "filename": "content/1.yaml",
    "time": "2020-09-14T22:33:40Z",
    "id": "ed1d4321",
    "name": "One",
    "description": "Here is number \"one\" this is good"
  },
  {
    "filename": "content/2yaml",
    "time": "2021-09-14T22:33:40Z",
    "id": "eg134841",
    "name": "Two",
    "description": "Here is number \"two\" best of all",
    "newkey": "value"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

For the record, you could use gojq, the Go implementation of jq, as it supports YAML:

```
gojq -n --yaml-input '[inputs | {filename: input_filename} + .] ' *.yaml
```

Note that gojq will sort the object keys.